# Bootstrap 4 create div before column

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the new Bootstrap 4 and I need to create a DIV before a bootstrap column in order to hide or show the columns when a button is pressed.

So what I need is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="menu-page" data-page="1">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-page" data-page="2">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I create this, the col-lg-6 divs lose all the bootstrap properties.

I need this to when a button is pressed it shows, using javascript, the div with the data-page associated to that button and hides the others.

How can I create this? Or there is a more simple way to do this?

Comment: Show the code how you add the div?

Comment: Maybe `container > row > 2 times col-12 (where menu-page is) > row > 2 times col-lg-6`?

Comment: make two `.row`s instead of one, and add the `.menu-page` class and the `data-page` attribute to the `.row`s. Then you don't need wrapping divs and lay-out will not be messed up at all.

Comment: give `col-lg-12` class name to `menu-page`

Comment: Why don’t you give an extra class to your column? You could hide that.

Comment: **"only columns may be immediate children of rows"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two `.row`s instead of one, and add the `.menu-page` class and the `data-page` attribute to the `.row`s. Then you don't need wrapping divs and lay-out will not be messed up at all.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row menu-page" data-page="1">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row menu-page" data-page="2">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you achieve the same style as you want it.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="menu-page col-lg-12" data-page="2">
         <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-page="1">
        <div class="menu-page col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" data-page="2">
        <div class="menu-page col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red; height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Bootstrap 4 ignores any new class after row. It only accepts bootstrap col but if still you want that class then you can add following css:

```
.menu-page {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And if you want different style in mobile then you can change the css